# Set retention time for states indivisually when joining KTable-KTable using KSQL

Tags: ksqldb

When using KTable join in KafaStream, I can set retention time individually for changelog topic and rocksDB as the following:

```java
clickStream.groupByKey()
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(200)))
                .reduce((oldValue, newValue) -> newValue, Materialized.<Integer, String,
                        WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("click").withRetention(Duration.ofSeconds(30000)));
```

Can I do the same when using ksql(KTable-KTable) for join?

for example:

```sql
select * from clicks 
left join conversions on clicks->param = conversions->param
```

and I would like retention time set on both clicks KTable and conversions KTable indivisually, for instance, 1 week for clicks and 1 month for conversions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not yet supported by KSQL.